# Add a curve to the selected ionic tab

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to add a curve to the selected ionic tab. I have the curve as an svg image, any ideas how to do it?
The curve will change depending on the activated tab

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding the curve using :before in the css of the selected button but it got hidden under the content, even if i use z-index